# Does singleton bean shares data with all the users in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am learning Spring framework. The first thing which I noticed is Application Context is application wise, so all the users will have same application context. But If all my beans are singleton in that application context, then does that mean data is same for all the users ? e.g. Employee bean is singleton but it should have different data user wise. How this is achieved in Spring ?

Comment: Why would you create a Spring managed "Employee" bean? Using Spring doesn't mean that you create a Spring bean out of every class possible.

Comment: Well, my EmployeeDetails bean will have employee information. Otherwise, what's the point using Spring ?

Comment: If you really need to ask this, then don't use Spring, at all. Spring is there to manage and build the architecture. When you only need it for your Employee bean, then it makes no sense.

Comment: I have just given the example of EmployeeDetails, there will be so many beans. 
I am just trying to understand here, how the singleton beans keep the different data to different users. Unlike their singleton behavior.

Comment: They can't, obviously, that's why you don't create Spring beans out of classes like Employee, User or whatever

Answer (score 2):

> Does singleton bean shares data with all the users in Spring?

Any state in a singleton bean (spring or without spring) is available for all **clients** of the bean.  A **client** of the bean is a spring component, a java instance, not a **end-user**. A client and a end-user are two distinct concepts that don't happen at the same level.
For example you could define a singleton bean that contains data for all `Employee`s : `EmployeeInMemoryRepository` while you could also make your application to allow only some end-users to access to some `Employee` data.

> e.g. Employee bean is singleton but it should have different data
> user wise. How this is achieved in Spring ?

An employee instance should never be a bean but a plain java instance as it contains data that are not designed to be shared among other services and besides you have no interest to make a bean an instance that you want to inject nowhere.
Why hell would you like to inject/autowire an employee such as  :

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService{ 
  private Employee employee
  public EmployeeService(Employee employee){
    this.employee=employee;
  }
  //...
}
```

What you want generally is passed an `Employee` as a parameter of a method and autowire services/singletons not specific to a user such as :

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService{ 

  private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
  public EmployeeService(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository){
    this.employeeRepository=employeeRepository;
  }
  public save(Employee employee){
    employeeRepository.save(employee);
  }
  //...
}
```

Comment: I think my Employee class would be the spring component so that it will be managed by Spring.
So there would @Component written above my Employee class. So ultimately Employee class will also be a bean.
Isn't it ?\

Answer (score 1):

A Spring Singleton differs from a Java Singleton. Spring manages the Singleton beans "per instance", so an Entity with the scope Singleton will be cached and returned every time it has the exact same values for its fields.

More on this here: https://dzone.com/articles/an-interview-question-on-spring-singletons

Comment: Above link says:
"To put it another way, when you define a bean definition and it is scoped as a singleton, then the Spring IoC container will create exactly one instance of the object defined by that bean definition. This single instance will be stored in a cache of such singleton beans, and all subsequent requests and references for that named bean will result in the cached object being returned."

This is confusing, cached object can create problem as all the users will get same info and again the cached one.....

Comment: Well that's exactly the idea of a singleton. Why would you want the users to get different instances of exactly the same object?